# How To Create a Custom Image Button When Click Play Sound or song?

Tags: dart, flutter

hey there like what we see in the image in below so i wondering how can make like this widget when i click to image play song

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdoLR.jpg)

Comment: so you want the UI design or you want to play the song ?

Comment: only any image in the middle to play the song like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdoLR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need **CircleAvatar** and **Inkwell** to do so. Following Code May help You.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: new Container(
            child:new Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  child: new Image.asset("images/crown.png"),
                ),
              )
            )
          )
        ),

      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: where i should put the song when i click button play song

Comment: You should look into this: https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-Music-Player

Comment: Use this package as a library haudioplayers 0.7.6 to play assert audio, audio from device and network audio.